# How to create a "Turn Off Screen" Action?

Tags: elementary-os, synapse

I recently moved to Elementary OS Luna. I especially use the Synapse Indicator launcher, because I like to work with my keyboard for everything.

In Synapse and in the Synapse Indicator (and I believe, generally, in the Gnome dekstop and I'll dare saying in all Linux DEs) there are "actions". Among actions there is *Shut Down*, *Restart*, *Lock Screen* etc. which can be run with Synapse and probably too from the command line.

I would like to create an action for *Turn Off Screen* (which is different from *Lock Screen*).

How can I create this action and be able to launch it from Synapse?

Comment: `xset dpms off` can turn off the screen. But how to achieve it with Synapse is out of my scope

Comment: It's a start. I suspect there must be somewhere some "action" launcher? Much like there are application launchers?

Comment: Never used Luna, so cant say about that. Not sure, but have a look in `/etc/xdg/menus`

Comment: I did a little reading about Luna and my guess is you can't do it via synapse, but there seem to be other options for mounting a launcher on the desktop.  What about a panel or the dock?

Comment: Ideally I want to do that with my keyboard.

Comment: It seems the command line to turn off screen is `xset dpms force off`. See [this link.](http://askubuntu.com/questions/7295/how-to-turn-off-the-display-via-the-command-line)

Comment: For now I made a small executable bash script using the command line above, called screen-off which I moved to my /usr/bin. It shows now as an application rather as an action. I would still like to know where those "actions" are defined and fix this properly.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe there's a detail I'm missing here, but you can create a .desktop file for whatever shell script you like and Synapse will launch it for you no problem.

Answer (score 0):

create a bash script file (.sh) then put this inside:

```
#!/bin/bash
sleep 0; xset dpms force off
```

sleep 0 determine how fast it will turn off

put the file in home folder then set the executable properties (chmod +755)

i think any launcher app will recognize it as an action/runable.

to lock the screen while it turned off, you can add command to the script depend on your DE.